# .htaccess redirect to url with same termination

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Can you please help me with my htaccess problem? It looks easy, but it is not.
I need to redirect (301) from `http://www.domain.com/en/` to `http://www.domain.com/a/en`.

I tried many ways to do it:

this makes loop on /a/en/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^a/en/$
RewriteRule ^en/$ http://www.domain.com/a/en/ [L,R=302]
```

this does not redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/en/$
RewriteRule ^en/$ http://www.domain.com/a/en/ [L,R=302]
```

this maybe could work, but I have more rules below I need to use, so I cant use it

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^a/en/$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^en/$ http://www.domain.com/a/en/ [L,R=302]
```

this makes loop on /a/en

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^en/$ http://www.domain.com/a/en/ [L,R=302]
```

this does not work

```
Redirect 302 ^/en/$ http://www.domain.com/a/en/
```

Right now I do not know  any other idea how to do it...
Thank you!

btw: I used 302 instead 301 due to better debug

Answer (score 0):

stick an index.html file in the directory that http://www.domain.com/en/ resolves to and put this in the head:

```
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http:///www.domain.com/a/en">
```

That should do the trick!

I hope this helps.

Comment: It could help, but it is complicated web application and it has to run on both http://www.domain.com and http://www.domain.com/a/en/. That is why I would rather use server htaccess solution.